# Web Farm file distribution

Tags: web-farm

I'm looking for a way to move files from my machine to several servers on a web farm.

I currently use beyond compare to move the files over; one BC session for each server on the farm. I'm fine with this because BC is fast and I like the control I have.

Our business gave me a new requirement of automatic file distribution of images. I've read a little about DFS but I'm not sure that is the route I want to take. I want the files to actually end up on the servers.

Any tools for this out there. A scripting option perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) in order to copy identical configuration files to all servers in a citrix farm, works great.

Comment: I'm trying to get our dev team to consider robocopy. Beyond Compare is a good manual solution but as with most manual solutions, mistakes are often made.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look into [MSDeploy](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MSDeployNewIISWebDeploymentTool.aspx) and [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wea2sca5.aspx) [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/346/web-deployment-tool/) might be a newer version of msdeploy

At my place I think we use [WanSync](http://www.ca.com/us/products/product.aspx?id=8232) though I couldn't be 100% sure because I'm not in that department.